# How longitudinal width will impact Bearing

Tags: php, latitude-longitude, bearing

**EDIT: For the most part I have figured this out using a formula that describes the changes in longitudinal width depending on your latitude.

[image: Formula for Longitudinal width]

[Link to wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Expressing_latitude_and_longitude_as_linear_units)
Now I haveto figure out how the result of this will change the bearing, any suggestions?**

This is the problem I face, in theory all "blocks" of Longitude and Latitude are equal, no matter where they are.
However the further you move away from the equator the more they narrow towards each other.
so at the tropics its safe to say the actual area is much less in one block then at the equator.

Before I continue let me just say my knowledge of geography ended in grade 9, so this just from my own research.

So I have a system that for simplicity works with blocks, and according to it all blocks are equal.

The problem arises when you take bearings into account. As the image illustrates (on the right) that is the actual bearing given by a device, and that exact angle is fed to the system. So the system interprets it as it receives it. (i.e. the solid line on the left.)

[image]

But that is inaccurate. So the solution is to alter the bearing according to how far away the device is from the equator to accommodate for this narrowing in longitude, and then arrive at the dotted arrow on the left which would be correct.

---

This is where I run out of intelligence,
*1: I dont know an equation to calculate the narrowing of longitude,* **SOLVED**
2: I'm not even sure i would be able to apply it and arrive at a coefficient to accurately offset the bearing.

And for a not I am doing this in php for now, however I will most likely end up porting this into an android client at a later stage.

Comment: I need to stress that it is the **BEARING** I wish to offset, I will not be plotting points in any way

Comment: i.e. I will get the devices bearing and location, and I need to offset the bearing depending on the distance from the equator, so that it will be accurate when i use it in an equation that treats the ground in terms of blocks of equal size.

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly the kind of problems [geographic coordinate systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system) were designed to deal with, so you should study those a bit, maybe select a library that handles this kind of calculations, like [this PHP library](https://github.com/treffynnon/Geographic-Calculations-in-PHP).

The earth isn't flat, don't try to "map" planar geometry onto a sphere just like that ...

And I'm a bit puzzled by your use of "tropics" - those are pretty close to the equator afaik....

Comment: +1 for linking to my code. I was just about to give an answer mentioning it myself!

Comment: Well then i guess i should have said half way between the equator and the poles? Also im not mapping the earth flat by any means, this is just a limitation I haveto overcome, and the system is not designed for doing long distance calculations, so i dont thing it will be a problem, thanks for the links, reading now

Comment: From what I have read it seems this touches on what I need, but I cant seem to digest it. [WikiLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Expressing_latitude_and_longitude_as_linear_units) and as for the library, that doesnt seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

Plotting points on planet earth is very difficult, not least because earth is not spherical, but is an oblate spheroid.

What you need to look at is something called "Greater Circle Distance" and "Haversine" formula. There's a good article about it here...

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

It took me a while to digest that when I faced the same issue you have.

Comment: Also the Vincenty formula which is more accurate: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html which I made a PHP port of here: https://github.com/treffynnon/Geographic-Calculations-in-PHP

Comment: dear lord, I wish I'd know about that before.

Comment: Very useful read, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, or I'm simply to dumb to see the answer.  Refer to one of my comments on the original question for clarification.